# Локализация Interface Builder Storyboard не работает

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iphone, локализация

Обновила я Xcode до 10ой версии и, соответственно, Swift до 4.2. И начались проблемы с приложениями. Одна из них это локализация. После обновления приложений хотела выкатить их в App Store. Но перед этим протестировала на iPhone. На iPhone у меня русский язык и регион Россия. Но отображается английский язык (который Base).

[image]

Также я локализировала фразы для UIAlertController.

[image]

И что самое забавное - работают только они. То есть когда я запускаю на iPhone своё приложение с Мака, то Storyboard на английском, а вот когда нажимаю кнопку где должен срабатывать UIAlertController то там всё на русском. Меняла язык на iPhone на китайский. Такая же ситуация - всё на английском, а UIAlertController на китайском.

В системе ничего не меняла. Я вообще только обновила Xcode.

[image]

[image]

Даже создала новый проект и сделала там локализацию русского. Тоже самое - показывает английский как по умолчанию.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Для тестирования локализации можно менять настройку application language. (Этот параметр доступен на 3 вашем скриншоте). Тогда не потребуется смена языка телефона

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал следующее:

1. Поубирать галочки локализации на сториборде без удаления файлов, потом поставить их заново.
2. Скопировать все файлы сториборда куда-инбудь, удалить из проекта создать новый сториборд с тем же именем, локализовать, затем заменить либо сами файлы либо исходный код на первоначальные.